# Recursive method to zip list?

Tags: python

I have got a nested list of list that looks like the following,

```py
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

However, I would like to find out a method to concatenate the first index of each list with the first index of the other list.

```py
list1 = [[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8,11],[3,6,9,12]]
```

I have tried doing list comprehension by using the following code

```
list1 = [[list1[j][i] for j in range(len(list1)) ] for i in range(len(list1[0])) ]

# gives me
# list1 = [[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8,11],[3,6,9,12]]
```

However, i was hoping alternative methods to achieve the same results, hopefully something that is simpler and more elegant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just apply ``zip``? Doing ``list(zip(*list1))`` is enough to get your output. If you need the nested sequences to be lists, ``list(map(list, zip(*list1)))`` will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) is a built-in method and does not require outside packages:

```py
>>> list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
>>> print([list(x) for x in zip(*list1)])
[[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Notice the `*list1`! This is needed since `list1` is a nested list, so the `*` unpacks that list's elements to the `zip` method to zip together. Then, since `zip` returns a list of tuples we simply convert them to lists (as per your request)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I would still like to know if doing it recursively by repeatedly calling the zip method is still possible

Answer (score 2):

A possible recursion solution can utilize a generator:

```
def r_zip(d):
   yield [i[0] for i in d]
   if d[0][1:]:
     yield from r_zip([i[1:] for i in d])

print(list(r_zip(list1)))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = min([len(list1[i]) for i in range(len(list1))])    
[[i[j] for i in list1] for j in range(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try using:

```
>>> list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
>>> list(map(list, zip(*list1)))
[[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
>>>
```